How to compute child items in tortoise orm
I have two simple models
class Realms(models.Model):
    """
    The Realm model
    """
    id = fields.IntField(primary_key=True)
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, description=f"Наименование пространства")
    realm_stocks: fields.ReverseRelation["Stocks"]

    def stocks_count(self) -> int:
        try:
            return len(self.realm_stocks)
        except NoValuesFetched:
            return -1
        
    class PydanticMeta:
        computed = ["stocks_count"]
        exclude = ["realm_stocks"]
            
    class Meta:
        table="msa_realms"

and
class Stocks(models.Model):
    """
    The Stocks model
    """
    id = fields.IntField(primary_key=True)
    mtr_description = fields.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    realm: fields.ForeignKeyRelation[Realms] = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.Realms", related_name="realm_stocks")

    class Meta:
        table="msa_stocks"

I need to count how many stocks in realm, but I don't need to export all stocks in response
@router.get("/msa_realms", response_model=List[Realm_Pydantic])
async def get_realms():
    return await Realm_Pydantic.from_queryset(Realms.all().prefetch_related('realm_stocks'))

When I try to get realms I've got an error
AttributeError: 'Realm' object has no attribute 'realm_stocks'
When I delete **exclude **property from PydanticMeta I've got all stocks, that I don't need
I need a response which will contain only stocks count property
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Realm 2",
"stocks_count": 100
}
